# Java EE - servlet is not forwarding to jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I very new to Java EE and I'm trying to just make a simple servlet that forwards a String to another jsp file but when the servlet runs all it shows is a white page

The index file works and there is not any error pop ups

these are the important parts of each of my files

index.jsp-

```
    <form action="prossessInfo"><br>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type = "submit" value ="send">
</form>
```

prossessInfo.java-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    String url = "/DisplayInfo.jsp";
    String usersName = request.getParameter("name");
    request.setAttribute("usersName", usersName);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

DisplayInfo.jsp-

```
<body>
<p>Hello ${usersName}</p><br>
</body>
```

I jut want the servlet to display the usersName provided through the index file then for the servlet to forward the usersName to the DisplayInfo.jsp file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the method for sending data through the form,.
So default its use get method to send data to the server.,
so you have to place your code inside the doGet method in the Servlet class.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String url = "/DisplayInfo.jsp";
    String usersName = request.getParameter("name");
    request.setAttribute("usersName", usersName);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

or You can mentioned the method in the form.

```
<form action="Controller" method="post"><br>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type = "submit" value ="send">
</form>
```